# How to find alternative (redundant) shortest paths with graph-tool

Tags: python-2.7, graph-tool

[Consider this graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vchvbk69tias1ke/chicago.pdf?dl=0)

I'm using Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm to find the shortest paths from all vertices to all other vertices. Then, I am using an edge filter to take the first edge and "hide" it, then recomputing the shortest path again to get an alternate, backup path. I only want a *single* alternate path, I do **not** wish to find *all* paths.

```
def compute_paths(source, dest):
    results = graph_tool.topology.shortest_path(g, source, dest, weights=weight)
    filteredge[results[1][0]] = 0
    g.set_edge_filter(filteredge)
    s_results = graph_tool.topology.shortest_path(g, source, dest, weights=weight)
    print "PRIMARY PATH:   %s" % ([g.vertex_index[x] for x in results[0]])
    print "SECONDARY PATH: %s" % ([g.vertex_index[x] for x in s_results[0]])
    g.set_edge_filter(None)
```

This works great if I call the function in a standalone manner, supplying it with a single pair of vertices, I get the output I would expect:

```
compute_paths(g.vertex(9), g.vertex(8))
```

Produces:

```
PRIMARY PATH:   [9, 3, 8]
SECONDARY PATH: [9, 4, 8]
```

However, attempting to get backup paths in a loop produces many empty backup paths where there should not be any. For example:

```
for v in g.vertices():
    for vv in g.vertices():
        if v == vv:
            continue
        else:
            compute_paths(v, vv)
```

For the shortest primary and backup paths between vertex 9 and vertex 8 will yield:

```
PRIMARY PATH:   [9, 3, 8]
SECONDARY PATH: []
```

I'm kind of stuck. I've tried creating a copy of the graph, using the GraphView class, and a couple other things, but I can't seem to make the backup path happen whenever I'm trying to compute it inside of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem.

Rather than setting the edge filter to `None`, I should have been resetting the boolean property map on the desired edge back to True.

The following yields me the results I need:

```
def compute_paths(source, dest):
    results = graph_tool.topology.shortest_path(g, source, dest, weights=weight)
    filteredge[results[1][0]] = 0
    g.set_edge_filter(filteredge)
    s_results = graph_tool.topology.shortest_path(g, source, dest, weights=weight)
    print "PRIMARY PATH:   %s" % ([g.vertex_index[x] for x in results[0]])
    print "SECONDARY PATH: %s" % ([g.vertex_index[x] for x in s_results[0]])
    filteredge[results[1][0]] = 1
```

I suppose I could still be setting the edge filter to `None` but that appears to be superfluous.